# How to take apache tcpdump on IBM iSeries system or capture soap envelope on tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, soap, ibm-midrange

We have a IBM iSeries system with is using apache middleware for incoming requests which then connects to tomcat through ajp connector which eventually runs java code.

We have a issue from customer end that they are not able to execute soap requests which works for other customers. I want to track the incoming soap envelope so that I can see the incoming request. Please help if there is any solution to track soap envelope on apache or on tomcat.

We tried to post the request using Postman and it works.
Basically client is facing 504 Gateway timeout issue on their end so we increased the timeouts in apache worker.properties and tomcat ajp connector. Still the are facing the same issue. Some of the soap requests went through well but some face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. Start trace with `STRCMNTRC`
2. Export dump to a file on the IFS using `DMPCMNTRC FORMAT(*PCAP)`
3. Open that file with wireshark for example

See [Performing a communications trace](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=trace-performing-communications)